# Wordpress is not writing <p> and <br> tags

Tags: html, wordpress, tags, format

I recently made a new theme but wordpress is stripping out the `<p>` and `<br>` tags, so the text is not shown well formatted. I am not writing together another html that can create this issue...

I've seen another questions but got no answer for me. Some of them mentioned about these functions:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

But no, i don't have any of these written in my functions.php

So why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put those two filter functions into your own functions.php file in your theme.  Without those two lines, the default setting for Wordpress is to filter the <p> and <br> tags.

Comment: Installing the wp plugin "PS Disable Auto Formatting" does the work. Like its name says, it disables the auto formatting. Although, i'd really know how to disable the auto formatting by myself since the filters in functions do not do the work.

Comment: @user3273960 Depending on how the plugin is constructed, you could potentially open it up and look through the code - look for calls to `add_filter` and `remove_filter`, especially if they mention `the_content` or `wpautop`. You might be able to figure out what the plugin is doing, and then copy the correct filters into your theme's `functions.php`. It might take a bit of trial and error - but if you have the inclination, read up on how Wordpress actions and filters work as well.